# How to increase the size of a block which an argument of a function points to?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
void foo(char *p)  
{  
    int i;
    int len = strlen(p);
    p = malloc(sizeof(char)*len+2);
    p[0] = '1';
    for(i=1; i<len+1; i++)
        p[i] = '0';
    p[i] = '\0';
}  

int main()  
{
    char p[2] = "1";

    foo(p);
    printf("%s\n", p);  // "10" expected

    return 0;
}
```

I realized that when I call `malloc` in `foo`,  `p`'s value has been changed, so array `p` in main will not be influence. But I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Remember to carefully free what you malloc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few wrong things with your code:

- In `main`, you declare `p` as an array that resides on the stack. Things that are on the stack cannot later be resized.
- Then in `foo` you want to change `p` to point to memory from the heap rather than to the array you have declared.

What you want to achieve can be done by initially allocating `p` with `malloc`, and then reallocating that memory again with `realloc`:

```
void foo (char **p) {
  *p = realloc(*p, 4);
}

int main (void) {
  char *p = malloc(2);
  foo(&p);
  ...
}
```

Notice that the argument of `foo` is a double pointer. That's because realloc may not only resize the memory block, but it may actually move it as well, so it will affect the value of the pointer.

Also note that the second argument of `realloc` is not the size you want to increment with, but rather the current size of the block plus the size to increment with.

Comment: @downvoter: would you leave a comment what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the address of the pointer and take `char**` as the function argument, i.e. pass `&p` as the argument and use `*p` inside `foo` to get the array address. BTW, the initialization of array needs to be done `char p[2] = {'1'}`;

Comment: +1, tho "BTW, the initialization of array needs to be done `char p[2] = {'1'}`".  Haven't checked it, but I think what the op did initializes the array like this: `char p[2] = {'1', '\0'}` (so it is null-terminated).